# NullPointerException when inserting into a database

Tags: java, android, sql, database, nullpointerexception

I'm developing a program using database.
I'm stuck on inserting the data typed from EditText, keep on getting NullPointerException.
Here is my code:

**AddBusDataActivity.java**

```
public class AddBusDataActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    SQLiteDatabase mBusDatabse;
    BusDatabaseHelper mBusDatabaseHelper;
    EditText mNumber;
    EditText mDestination;
    EditText mArrivalTime;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add);

        mBusDatabaseHelper = new BusDatabaseHelper(AddBusDataActivity.this, Constants.DATABASE_NAME, null, Constants.VERSION);

        mNumber = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.number_text);
        mDestination = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.destination_text);
        mArrivalTime = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.arrival_time);
    }
    public void addBusActivityButton(View view) {
        mBusDatabse = mBusDatabaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        BusData bus = new BusData(mNumber.getText().toString(), mDestination.getText().toString(), Integer.valueOf(mArrivalTime.getText().toString()));
        mBusDatabaseHelper.addBusData(bus); // error here
        mBusDatabaseHelper.close();
        Toast.makeText(AddBusDataActivity.this, "Bus data successfully added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        this.finish();
    }
}
```

**BusDatabaseHelper.java**

```
public class BusDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    SQLiteDatabase mBusDatabase;

    public BusDatabaseHelper(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, name, factory, version);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("create table "+ Constants.TABLE_NAME + " (" + Constants.KEY_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " +
                Constants.NUMBER + " text not null, " + Constants.DESTINATION + " text not null, " + Constants.ARRIVAL_TIME + " integer not null);");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("drop table " + Constants.TABLE_NAME + ";");
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public void addBusData(BusData busData) {
        ContentValues busValues = new ContentValues();
        busValues.put(Constants.NUMBER, busData.getmNumber());
        busValues.put(Constants.DESTINATION, busData.getmDestination());
        busValues.put(Constants.ARRIVAL_TIME, busData.getmArrivalTime());
        mBusDatabase.insert(Constants.TABLE_NAME, null, busValues); // error here
    }
}
```

**Error message**

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.id11201478.exercise6.BusDatabaseHelper.addBusData(BusDatabaseHelper.java:36)
            at com.id11201478.exercise6.AddBusDataActivity.addBusActivityButton(AddBusDataActivity.java:36)
```

I have separate **Constants.java** class for storing thoses values.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what you get when you print busValues?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `mBusDatabase` in `BusDatabaseHelper` is never initialised and therefore is null. Dereferencing it on line 36 causes your NPE.

You don't actually need it if you modify `addBusData` to grab it each time:

```
public void addBusData(BusData busData) {
    ContentValues busValues = new ContentValues();
    busValues.put(Constants.NUMBER, busData.getmNumber());
    busValues.put(Constants.DESTINATION, busData.getmDestination());
    busValues.put(Constants.ARRIVAL_TIME, busData.getmArrivalTime());
    getWritableDatabase().insert(Constants.TABLE_NAME, null, busValues);
}
```

Comment: How can I initialise it??

Answer (score 1):

The variable

```
BusDatabaseHelper.mBusDatabase
```

is null. 
You need to initialize it!

Otherwise how does the system knows what mBusDatabase is

try to add this before insert

```
mBusDatabase= this.getWritableDatabase();
```

Comment: Hwo can I initialise it??

Comment: try to add  mBusDatabase= this.getWritableDatabase();  before insert

Comment: I put it in onCreate() as mBusDatabase = mBusDatabaseHelper.getWritableDatabase(); just below but gives same error :( (I put it just below mBusDatabaseHelper = new BusDatabaseHelper(AddBusDataActivity.this, Constants.DATABASE_NAME, null, Constants.VERSION);)

Comment: it should add before mBusDatabase.insert(Constants.TABLE_NAME, null, busValues);  lol never mind